# RecyclerView как в ВК (убрать поля и скругление углов в CardView)

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Хочу сделать свой `RecyclerView` как в ВК, что бы не было этих в `CardView` закруглений и отступов по краям.

Конкретно что бы статья доходила до боковых стенок и между статьями был промежуток.

Где про это почитать? или подскажите как сделать это?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы путаете понятия поля (*margins*) и отступы (*paddings*).

Поля (данного элемента) – это расстояние между границей родительского элемента и границей данного (дочернего) элемента.

Отступы (данного элемента) – это расстояние между границей данного элемента и границей его дочерних элементов.

Вам нужно убрать *поля* (слева и справа) у виджета `CardView`.

Самый простой виджет `CardView` можно построить вот так:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
```

Теперь добавим этому `CardView` поля (*margins*) сверху и снизу:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">
```

И уберем скругление углов:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
```

Выглядеть это будет так (для наглядности я добавил внутрь `CardView` `LinearLayout` с двумя `TextView`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде как получилось именно то, что Вам необходимо.